# Change the class of wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have problems with wordpress menu level classes.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

this is the code i used to generate my menu,

First level menu id is

> ul id="menu-home"

second level class is

> ul class="sub-menu"

but my third level menu also has same class as second level

> ul class="sub-menu"

is there any way to change the class of third level or some other solution???

please help..
thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the right answer from here
[original link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61220/change-the-class-of-wordpress-menu)

Thanks to Amit [profile](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/17968/amit)

Here is the code

```
class wpse61220_submenu_class extends Walker_Nav_Menu {  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub-menu-".$depth."\">\n";  }}
```

usage:

```
wp_nav_menu( array('walker' => new wpse61220_submenu_class() ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how are you creating your menus, but according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu you can pass a parameter (menu_class) to set menu's class or the container class:

```
<?php 
    $options = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'menu_class'      => 'sub-menu', 
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
); ?>
```

Or if you want to apply some **CSS** or **jQuery** selector, do something like this:

```
ul#menu-home ul.sub-menu ul.sub-menu
```

And then you'll have access to the third-level menu.

Comment: i can access in css or jquery but the problem is i have done some styling and jquery to the second level menu is inheriting to the third level also,i don't want that.

Comment: Then you can use the following CSS rule: ul#menu-home > ul.sub-menu it will apply styles only to the second ul, not the third one. But this is a little buggy on IE7

Answer (score 0):

if your work is too smal you can use this trick.

open menus page from appearance and from top navigator choose "screen options".

now select "CSS CLASSES".

now check menu item , there is new Optional field => "css classes(optional)" name

that's it. ;) . i hope so be lucky.